# [Nested interface/type]: How to declare function return types inside a class in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have some big classes with functions with complex return objects that I want to refactor.

```
class BigClass {
    ...
    getReferenceInfo(word: string): { isInReferenceList:boolean, referenceLabels:string[] } {
    ...
    }
}
```

I want to do something like this (declare it close to my function):

```
class Foo {
    ...
    type ReturnObject = { isInReferenceList:boolean, referenceLabels:string[] };
    getReferenceInfo(word: string):ReturnObject   {
      ...
      }
}
```

But right now Typescript only lets me declare interfaces/types outside of the class:

```
type ReturnObject = { isInReferenceList:boolean, referenceLabels:string[] };
class Foo {
    ...
    getReferenceInfo(word: string):ReturnObject   {
      ...
      }
}
```

Is there a way to have nested interfaces in Typescript?

Comment: No, but I need the same feature.

Comment: It's not possible to assign type to class, but you can make namespace with class and this type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this isn't currently supported.  There is an [existing suggestion in GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7061) to support allowing a `class` to also act as a namespace for type declarations.  If you care about this feature you might want to go to the GitHub issue and give it a  and/or describe your use case if it's especially compelling.

The current workaround is to use [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-namespaces-with-classes) like this:

```
// separate namespace 
// not close to your method either 
namespace Foo {
  // must export the type in question 
  export type ReturnObject = {
    isInReferenceList: boolean,
    referenceLabels: string[]
  };
}

class Foo {
  // must refer to the type as fully qualified by namespace 
  getReferenceInfo(word: string): Foo.ReturnObject {
    return null!;
  }
}
```

It's obviously not perfect, and might not even be worth it if your use case is "get the type declaration closer to the method that's using it", which this doesn't even fix.

Oh well, hope that helps anyway.  Good luck!